# How to make slides on the pages using html and css

Tags: html, css

In the below html I want to introduce sliders, but I am unable to do that.I want to slide the slide-1 to the left so that slide-2 should be visible.
How to achieve this?

Below is the example image: Here in the image forfet about the arrows, I need these 3 circles only.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>

.slide-1{
   font-family: "Quicksand";
}

.slide-2{
   font-family: "Quicksand";
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>

<div class="slide-1">
  <p text-wrap>This is the slide 1 content</p>
</div>

<div class="slide-2">
<p text-wrap>This is slide 2 content.And this will only be visible when user touch and side to the left of slide-1.How is this possible?</p></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: Go through carousel tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: @Roy Hey, it solved my problem..please write it as an answer..so that I can accept this..and also upvote if its a genuine question.thanks

Comment: nice, good luck coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Bootstrap:

https://getbootstrap.com/

> Build responsive, mobile-first projects on the web with the world's
>   most popular front-end component library.
>
> Bootstrap is an open source toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and
>   JS. Quickly prototype your ideas or build your entire app with our
>   Sass variables and mixins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt
>   components, and powerful plugins built on jQuery.

Has a nice component called **Carousel**. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/
Here is an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://content.nike.com/content/dam/one-nike/en_lu/SU16/Running/Free-xcat/Desktop/SU16_RN_NikeFree_InnovationHub_M_CDP_P1.jpg.transform/full-screen/SU16_RN_NikeFree_InnovationHub_M_CDP_P1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.pandasecurity.com/spain/mediacenter/src/uploads/2014/08/free.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://blog.bufferapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/6110974997_8b0dfa13a0_b.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this example, it contains the leagues of the script that you can use, in order to manipulate the rhythm of the transition, and you can play with the style

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main {

    width:50%;

    max-width: 1000px;
    margin:40px auto;
}
.slides {
    width:100%;
}

.slides img {
    width:70%;
    height:100%

}

.slidesjs-pagination {

    list-style:none;
    overflow:hidden;

}

.slidesjs-pagination li {
    float:left;
}

.slidesjs-pagination li a {
    border-radius: 100px;
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    color:rgba(220,220,220,0);
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: rgba(220,220,220,0.6);

}

.slidesjs-pagination li a:hover {
    background:#000;
}

.slides .active {
    background-color: rgba(180,180,180,0.6);
    color: rgba(180,180,180,0);
}

.slidesjs-navigation{
    background-color: rgba(220,220,220,0.6);
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:13.6px 20px;
    float:right;
}

</style>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="slides">
            <img src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/slideshow/2.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/slideshow/3.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/slideshow/4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/slideshow.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.seguridad-maestro.tk/js/jquery.slides.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```